# bokeh hovertool how to show multiple tooltip entries for multi_line segments of identical coordinates

Tags: python, tooltip, bokeh

When several objects of the same size are in the same position on a chart, although only the top of the 'stack' is visible, I expect to see a description of all of them in the tooltip box.

- This is the behaviour when using circle plots for example:

```
    from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_notebook, show, ColumnDataSource
    output_notebook()

    source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(
        x=[1, 2, 2, 4, 5],
        y=[2, 5, 5, 2, 7],
        desc=['A', 'b', 'C', 'd', 'E'],
    ))

    TOOLTIPS = [
        ("index", "$index"),
        ("desc", "@desc"),
    ]

    p = figure(plot_width=400, plot_height=400, tooltips=TOOLTIPS,
               title="Mouse over the dots")

    p.circle('x', 'y', size=20, source=source)

    show(p)
```

[image]

- However, in the following example using a multi_line plot, only one record is visible in the tooltip box, although two segments have the exact same coordinates

```
    from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_notebook, show, ColumnDataSource
    output_notebook()

    source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(
        x=[(1, 2), (2, 3), (4, 5), (2, 3)],
        y=[(2, 5), (5, 4), (2, 7), (5, 4)],
        desc=['A', 'b', 'C', 'D'],
    ))

    TOOLTIPS = [
        ("index", "$index"),
        ("desc", "@desc"),
    ]

    p = figure(plot_width=400, plot_height=400, tooltips=TOOLTIPS,
               title="Mouse over the dots")

    p.multi_line(xs='x', ys='y', line_width=4, source=source)

    show(p)
```

[image]

**How can I get the tooltip to show multiple entries for multi_lines?**

Answer (score 1):

That's not possible, but you could do both: `p.multi_line(...)` and `p.circle(...)` (in exactly this order). If you want you can make circles small enough (e.g. `size = 5`) so they are not visible. Then you could specify those circles as the only renderers for the hover like this:

```
circles = p.circle(...)
p.hover.renderers = [circles]
```

Comment: thanks for your quick response, I gave you an upvote because it is an improvement, but there is still the issue of points being more sparse than lines. So when you hover over a line, most of the time it will not show the tooltip using this method, only if you hover over the extremities

Comment: See updated answer (you need to exclude `multi_line` from the hover)

Comment: I totally get that, but this will not fill the blanks between the points. Usually a user can hover over any part of a line and see the tooltip, but with the proposed solution, it will only show on the part that is covered with a circle... Which is better than before but still not ideal